# How to apply offset to row in Bootstrap Twitter?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, offset

I have row that should have offset on both ends. Here is example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 offset-xs-2">
      <input type="submit" name="btn" value="OK" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="button" value="Open" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 ">
      <input type="button" name="page" class="btn btn-primary " value="Page">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to apply offset to this grid system that will move the buttons to the center? That should work on all screen sizes the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Bootstrap 4 syntax with a 3.3.7 CSS link.

Bootstrap 4: `offset-xs-2`

Bootstrap 3: `col-xs-offset-2`

I changed `offset-xs-2` to `col-xs-offset-2`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">
      <input type="submit" name="btn" value="OK" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="button" value="Open" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 ">
      <input type="button" name="page" class="btn btn-primary " value="Page">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```